# Android: nothing happens on request runtime permission?

Tags: android

I want to request permission to read external storage on runtime. When I click on a `Button` the app should ask for permission, but the dialog does not show up when button is clicked. Code (This is from a `Fragment`):

```
    private Button photo;

    //Constants
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2339;
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 4435;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        photo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
        photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //start permission check for gallery
                //check if permission is granted
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //if permission is not granted, ask for permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }else{
                    //if permission already granted, start gallery intent.
                    uploadPhotoToFirebase();
                }

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage
                    .getInstance()
                    .getReference("profile_images/"+FirebaseAuth
                            .getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getUid()
                    );

            storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    //File successfully uploaded
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //File upload not successful
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //Permission to read external storage GRANTED
                    uploadPhotoToFirebase();

                }else{
                    //Permission to read external storage DENIED
                }
        }
    }

    private void uploadPhotoToFirebase(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
    }

}
```

Anyone knows why the dialog requesting permission does not show up here?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside of the if block, does it get to the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` line?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Give me 1min I'll check!

Comment: you got correct targetSdk in your manifest?

Comment: Do you have the `<uses-permission>` element for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke it does reach that line.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Target is set to 25 and minimum to 24

Comment: @Carlton Well that's good. I'd follow CommonsWare's advice and check the manifest

Comment: @CommonsWare No I have not. Does it need to be set, even if you ask for permission on runtime?

Comment: @Carlton It does. "On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as described in Declaring Permissions." - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I added it and now the dialog show up. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Thanks for the help, it works now!

Comment: If you want, you can answer the question so I can upvote&accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dialog to appear, you need to:

- Have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher
- Have the permission(s) that you are requesting also in the manifest, with `<uses-permission>` elements
- Be running on Android 6.0 or higher

Comment: Thanks again CommonsWare. I bought your book recently, must say that it's really good, great job!